# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined[Slider]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

my slider is throwing an error of **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined**. I have used material ui as a component and redux-form. I get this error while changing the slider. The state of slider value is preserved where it is left. How to overcome this issue?

```
const renderSlider = ({ input, sliderValue }) => (
    <Slider
      min={0}
      max={100}
      step={1}
      {...input}
      value={input.value !== '' ? input.value : sliderValue}
      onChange={(event, value) => input.onChange(value)}
    />
);
<div>
    <Field
        name="slider"
        component={renderSlider}
        sliderValue={50}
    />
</div>
```

Here is an error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a onchange function ? If yes can you also show that .Also,  can you how the detail  error log from the console ( which setData it is referencing. Because looking at the code it's hard to know where the set data is being called.)

Comment: Yes you can see onChange function in Slider component. The error is shown in the updated question.